# Can we connect QPushButton to change values of QSlider?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpushbutton, qslider

I have two push buttons labeled with `+` and `-` probably, I need to increase and decrease the values of the slider using these push buttons, Please help me to code this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create slots `plus()` and `minus()`:

```
public slots:
    void plus();
    void minus();
```

Then connect the clicked signal with the respective slot:

```
connect({your minus QPushButton}, SIGNAL(clicked()) , this, SLOT(minus()));
connect({your plus QPushButton}, SIGNAL(clicked()) , this, SLOT(plus()));
```

In each slot implement the increase or decrease tasks.

```
void {your widget}::plus()
{
    {your slider}->setValue({your slider}->value()+1);
}

void {your widget}::minus()
{
    {your slider}->setValue({your slider}->value()-1);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code as per your helpful comments, i'm new to Qt
so help me to solve this error 
error: 'horizontalSlider' : undeclared identifier

my cpp file :
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), ui->horizontalSlider, SLOT(plus()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::plus()
{
   ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(horizontalSlider -> value()+1);

}

Comment: @Yana add #include <QSlider>

Comment: @Yana and #include <QPushButton>

Comment: @Yana change  ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(horizontalSlider -> value()+1) to  ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(ui->horizontalSlider -> value()+1)

Comment: @Yana If my answer will help you mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, with a C++11 capable environment, with lambdas instead of new slots

```
connect(minusButton, &QPushButton::clicked, slider,
        [slider] () { slider->setValue(slider->value() - 1 );});
connect(plusButton, &QPushButton::clicked, slider,
        [slider] () { slider->setValue(slider->value() + 1 );});
```